# Laziness in folding the result of a map operation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

**Why is this function causing high memory usage, and are there any suggestions to reduce memory usage?**

**EDIT**: A more minimal example

Example (1) GC sees that each element is not needed after printed as little memory is used:

```
printThings = readThing >=> mapM_ (parseThing >>> print)
```

Example (2) Entire list is kept in memory

```
printThings = readThing >=> map parseThing >>> print
```

Note in my exact question below, I fold over the map result, hoping to only evaluate each element and then have that element freed by GC.

---

I have a program that reads in data, parses it, and reduces it. As a *minimal* example:

```hs
aFoo :: FilePath -> IO ()
aFoo = readFile >=> lines >>> map convertStringToB >>> reduceBsToC >>> print
reduceBsToC = foldl' bToC base
```

To be more specific, I am reading in a file lazily with:

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
actualFoo = B.readFile >=> B.split '\n' >>> map convertByteStringToB >>> reduceBsToC >>> print)
```

I'm seeing lots of memory usage for this program (~4GB with my input) for what  appears to be either:

- The entire file is being read into memory
- Or more likely, the entire result of `map` is being stored in memory

I was expecting the [B] created by `map convertByteStringStringToB` to be read lazily by the fold. If I just print [B] I don't see this behavior, and far less memory gets used (~10MB):

```
readFoo :: FilePath -> IO [ByteString]
readFoo = B.readFile >=> B.split '\n' >>> return
printFoo :: FilePath -> IO ()
printFoo = readFoo >=> mapM_ (convertByteStringToB >>> print)
-- Lazily reading in file and converting each 'line'
```

I know the implementation of `foldl'` is:

```
foldl' f z []     = z
foldl' f z (x:xs) = let z' = z `f` x 
                    in seq z' $ foldl' f z' xs
```

I assumed that `(x:xs)` uses a thunk to represent `xs`, otherwise the entire result of the `map` operation would be in memory.

---

**EDIT**

`convertByteStringToC` and `reduceBsToC` were requested for clarification:

`convertByteStringToC` is a [Megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-6.5.0) function which is too long for this format.

`reduceBsToC` uses [fgl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.6.0.0). (simplified):

```
type MyGraph = Gr UNode UEdge
reduceBsToC :: MyGraph -> B -> MyGraph
reduceBsToC gr End = gr
reduceBsToC gr b = maybe makeDefault setGraph (tryAddToGr gr b)
```

Comment: What are `convertByteStringToB` and `reductBsToC`? The reason is probably in there.

Comment: Thanks for including a Minimal Example! Can you also rewrite it to be Complete and Verifiable? See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduceBsToC` is producing a `Gr` graph. It is represented as a `Map`, which is not a lazy or streaming structure (it's a tree). Thus the fold is accumulating a graph possibly as large as the original list.

Comment: It’s actually combining data into nodes in the graph. In the end there’s only 7 nodes in the Gr graph, so I don’t think that’s the source. Nodes are never deleted so the graph has a maximum size of 7 nodes.

Comment: After more toying around. It looks like Graph is certainly a factor here. But it's not the size of the graph that's the problem. Something else in the implementation is preventing the list items from getting freed. I'll update when I have more.

Comment: @MikeLui Are we sure the graph isn't collecting thunks? You're using `foldl'`, which makes the graph strict, but it doesn't necessarily make the data *inside* the graph strict. It just ensures evaluation to weak-head normal form.

Comment: @DarthFennec That's definitely what it is. I threw in a bunch of bang patterns and saw resident memory drop from 4GB to 10MB. Going to narrow it down and update.

Answer (score 1):

Barring adding a complete and verifiable example, I was able to hunt down the issue.

My Megaparsec computations were getting lazily evaluated at the very end during the final `print`, meaning the entire file was read in to generate the parse computations, but not executing right away.

I added [strict fields](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Data_types#Strict_fields) to the data constructors getting `return`ed in my parsers. E.g.:

```
data MyParsedData = MyParsedData { value1 :: !Int, value2 :: !Int }
```

This forces the following to parse immediately upon building the MyParsedData, instead of the parsing getting deferred.

```
myParse = do
    val1 <- parseVal1
    val2 <- parseVal2
    return $ MyParsedData val1 val2
```

Additionally, I tried forgoing the strict fields, and instead used 
[BangPatterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html), which also corrected the problem. This involved adding the BangPatterns pragma, and using them when pattern matching my data later on in the foldl' accumulating function (referencing the original question):

```
tryAddtoGr gr (MyParsedData !val1 !val2) = ...
```

This forces execution of parse during the fold.

**Clarification**: MyParsedData is built just before it gets pattern matched, when it is used in the fold.